# How to get model queue name for a given dynamic queue (WebSphere MQ)?

Tags: ibm-mq

I've got a model queue (say, MY.MODEL.QUEUE). I'm opening it in process A and get a dynamic queue created (say, AMQ.WHATEVER). I send a message to another queue, specifying AMQ.WHATEVER as a ReplyTo queue.

Now, process B receives the message, and replies to the dynamic queue. However, in B I need to know what model queue AMQ.WHATEVER is related to.

I couldn't find any MQINQ Selector to inquire for that. Is there any way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't get there from here.  :-)

There is no reverse-resolution of queues, QMgrs, etc.  If you need to know the model queue that was used, it will be necessary for the programs involved to specify enough of a root name to make the dynamic queues identifiable.

For example, when you open MY.MODEL.QUEUE, specify a DynamicQName of MY.MODEL.QUEUE.* or similar.  Then instead of a dynamic queue AMQ.WHATEVER you end up with a dynamic queue name of MY.MODEL.QUEUE.WHATEVER.  You can set the dynamic queue prefix in the administered objects for JMS or as part of the API for JMS and all the other languages.  [Here](http://bit.ly/bkp42P) is the doc page that explains the name prefixing.